# Terraform get list index on for_each

Tags: terraform

Terraform newbie here.
I'd like to iterate a list using `for_each`, but it seems like the key and value are the same:

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = "default"
  region  = "us-east-1"
}

variable "vpc_cidrs" {
  default = ["10.0.0.0/16", "10.1.0.0/16"]
}

resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  for_each             = toset(var.vpc_cidrs)
  cidr_block           = each.value
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  tags                 = { Name = "Company0${each.key}" }
}
```

I'd like the tag Name to be `"Name" = "Company01"` and `"Name" = "Company02"` but according to `terraform apply`, I get:
`"Name" = "Company010.0.0.0/16"` and `"Name" = "Company010.1.0.0/16"`
What am I missing?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Found an easy solution using the [index](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/index.html) function:

```
tags = { Name = "Company0${index(var.vpc_cidrs, each.value) + 1}" }
```

Comment: This solution also works well on a for statement.  [ for x in data.aws_availability_zones.available.names : cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr_block, 8, index(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names, x)) ]

Answer (score 37):

There is also another way of achieving the wanted result without using `index()`:

change the following three lines:

```
for_each   = { for idx, cidr_block in var.vpc_cidrs: cidr_block => idx}
cidr_block = each.key
tags       = { Name = format("Company%02d", each.value + 1) }
```

- the `for_each` will use a map of `cidr_block` to `index` mapping as returned by  `for`
- the `cidr_block` can then just use the `each.key` value
- and in the `tags` also use `format()` on `each.value` to have a two digit with leading zeros of the `index`

Full example will be:

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = "default"
  region  = "us-east-1"
}

variable "vpc_cidrs" {
  default = ["10.0.0.0/16", "10.1.0.0/16"]
}

resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  for_each             = { for idx, cidr_block in var.vpc_cidrs: cidr_block => idx}
  cidr_block           = each.key
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  tags                 = { Name = format("Company%02d", each.value + 1) }
}
```

Comment: how do you do this inside a dynamic block?

Comment: same way actually.... just the reference is different as it will be prefixed with the dynamic block name as in `dynamic "name"`  will become `name.each.value` instead of `each.value` .. same for key

Answer (score 14):

When [`for_each` is used with a set](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#the-each-object), `each.key` and `each.value` are the same.

To generate strings like "Company01", "Company02", etc., you need the index of each CIDR block in the list. One way to do this is to create a local map using a [`for` expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#for-expressions) like:

```
locals {
  vpc_cidrs = {for s in var.vpc_cidrs: index(var.vpc_cidrs, s) => s}
}

resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  for_each             = local.vpc_cidrs
  cidr_block           = each.value
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  tags                 = { Name = "Company0${each.key}" }
}
```

As a bonus, you can use the [format](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/format.html) function to build the zero-padded name string:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  ...
  tags                 = { Name = format("Company%02d", each.key) }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `count` function and use the index to do this:

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = "default"
  region  = "us-east-1"
}

variable "vpc_cidrs" {
  type = list(string)
  default = ["10.0.0.0/16", "10.1.0.0/16"]
}

resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  count = length(var.vpc_cidrs)
  cidr_block           = var.vpc_cidrs[count.index]
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  tags                 = { Name = "Company0${count.index}" }
}
```

Comment: @Moshe Thanks for calling my attention on this, I didn't test this thoroughly. But still I could come up with something alternative for this using count. I just updated my answer

Comment: sorry, still not correct. the loop would not give you the var values, just the index. in the question I stated I need both. review other suggested solutions, they provide the answer(s)

Comment: @Moshe The loop will give you the var values, on `var.vpc_cidrs[count.index]` as the index increase it will loop over all the elements in the list

Answer (score -1):

One of the comments was asking about how to achieve this use an index when using `for_each` inside a [dynamic block](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html).

#### Short answer

This can be done by refering to `<name-of-dynamic-block>.key` (*key* is the index).

---

#### An example

##### Use case

I'll take a use case where I have one S3 bucket that have multiple folders inside it, and each folder has a dedicated cloudfront distribution pointing to it.

##### What I want in the scope of AWS

Let's say I have 2 folders inside the s3 bucket: *name1* and *name2*.

So I'll have to create an `aws_s3_bucket_policy` that looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "<arn-of-cloudfront-distribution-1>"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::some-bucket/name1/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "<arn-of-cloudfront-distribution-2>"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::some-bucket/name2/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

(*) The creation of the cloudfront distributions was removed for brevity.

##### How to achieve this with Terraform

So I have a list of folders that needs to be created inside my s3 bucket:

```
variable "all_s3_folders" {
  type        = list(string)
  default     = []
  description = "All folders inside the bucket"
}
```

For each folder I created a *cloudfront distribution* (removed for brevity) and an *cloudfront origin access identity* (see [oai](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html)) resources.

We will create those resources based on a `count` on the number of folders:

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity" "oai" {
  count = length(var.all_s3_folders)
  comment = "some-comment"
}
```

Now we need to add each folder (+ its relevant cloudfront distrobution and oai) as an entry in the bucket policy.

I want to use dynamic block with `for_each` inside it but without relying on `count.index`.

But I'll still have to iterate over the `aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity` resources with an index.

So,

In order to use an index when using `for_each` inside a dynamic block you just refer to `<name-of-dynamic-block>.key` - here it's `statement.key`

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "my-doc" {
  dynamic "statement" {
    for_each = var.folders_array
    content {
      effect = "Allow"

      actions = [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ]

      resources = [
        "${aws_s3_bucket.my_s3_bucket.arn}/${statement.value}/*" # <--Using statement value
      ]

      principals {
        type = "AWS"
        identifiers = [some_cloudfront_resource[statement.key].id] # <--Using statement key
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: when using a simple string list, key is not the index, it is the actual value