# Data manipulation on Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to do a DMS infrastructure, but I'm stuck due to quotas. I'm trying to the following:

1. I got a list of 64 DBs => replicated_db separate in chunk of 50
2. create x DMS instances => X is number of chunk of the list 1)
3. associate DMS replication task to DMS instances separated into chunks of the list 1)

Points 1 and 2 are OK, but I'm stuck on the 3rd.

What I have already done:

```
    # Create a new replication instance
resource "aws_dms_replication_instance" "dms_instance" {
  count = length(chunklist(var.replicated_db, 50))
  allow_major_version_upgrade  = true 
  apply_immediately            = false
  auto_minor_version_upgrade   = true
  allocated_storage            = var.allocated_storage
  availability_zone            = module.rds-mssql.db_instance_availability_zone[0]
  engine_version               = "3.4.7"
  multi_az                     = var.dms_multi_az
  preferred_maintenance_window = var.maintenance_window
  publicly_accessible          = false
  replication_instance_class   = var.replication_instance_class
  replication_instance_id      = "${var.identifier}-dms-${count.index}"
  replication_subnet_group_id  = aws_dms_replication_subnet_group.dms_subnet_group[0].id
  vpc_security_group_ids = flatten([
    var.vpc_security_group_ids,
    "sg-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "sg-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "sg-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    ]
  )

  tags = var.tags
}

resource "aws_dms_replication_task" "dms_replication_task" {
  for_each = var.replicated_db

  migration_type           = "full-load"
  replication_instance_arn = aws_dms_replication_instance.dms_instance[*].replication_instance_arn
  replication_task_id      = "${var.identifier}-${replace(each.value, "_", "-")}-replication-task"
  table_mappings         = file("${var.path_table_mapping}/table_mappings.json")
  source_endpoint_arn    = aws_dms_endpoint.dms_endpoint_source[each.value].endpoint_arn
  target_endpoint_arn    = aws_dms_endpoint.dms_endpoint_target[each.value].endpoint_arn

  tags = var.tags

  depends_on = [
    aws_dms_endpoint.dms_endpoint_source,
    aws_dms_endpoint.dms_endpoint_target,
  ]
}
```

Could someone help me with this data manipulation?

Comment: It won't work because you are using `count` meta-argument for the first resource and then `for_each` for the second resource.

Comment: I know my code is not working ^^.I'm looking for a solution to make all of this working

Comment: Well it's rather simple: use either `count` of `for_each` in both resources, but not a combination of the two. Additionally, without the variable `replicated_db` value, there is not much that can be offered.

Comment: You could e.g. use the index (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61343796/terraform-get-list-index-on-for-each) functionality to get the index of each.value within the list, divide that index by 50 (the chunk size) and round down, that should yield the correct replication inactive index. Alternatively just use count on the second resource as well, then you already have the index, get the data from the list based on the index and do the same index math to get the instance index.

Comment: as mentioned is a list of 64 DB
`replicated_db = [
    "database01",
    "database02",
    "database03",
    "database04",
    "database05",
    "database06",
    "database07",
    "database08",
    "database09",
    "database10",
    [...]
    "database60",
    "database61",
    "database62",
    "database63",
    "database64",
]`

If needed I can change the variable type and/or structure

Comment: You could do two things: 1. use `for_each` in the first resource, with `toset` and then use resource chaining or 2. use `count` in the second resource instead of `for_each` and use indexes, i.e., `count.index`.

Comment: Thx, @luck2302, it worked. There is the functional block 

`replication_instance_arn = aws_dms_replication_instance.dms_instance["${floor(index(var.replicated_db, each.value) / var.chunk_db_numer)}"].replication_instance_arn`